# Unable to click on elements that are outside of parent element using Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am building some functional tests for Chrome using protractor. This is my scenario: I have to open a html dialog and open a dropdown in that and select an option from that drop down. That drop down has like 20 options so drop down options list spreads out of the dialog box. I am able to click on options that falls inside the dialog but I could not click on options that are outside of the dialog.
I am getting error as:

> Element is not clickable at point (123, 637). Other element would receive the click

is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What do you mean by options outside of the dialog? Could you add more details to the problem description - the HTML representation of the dialog, your test and the error stacktrace? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From information given, for me, it looks like you are trying to access dropdown options elements separately, and selector you are using for elements inside a dialog is not applicable to those outside, so I would suggest to select element that has all of the options nested inside (or create one if needed) and click on elements as child elements of that container, it may look like:

```
var dropDownOptions = element(by.id('optionsContainerId'))
                             .all(by.<options locator>);
dropDownOptions.get(<index of option>)
               .click();
```

And generally, to access elements outside of parent element (those that are outside of current element you have selected) you could use `by.xpath` locator. See [docs](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath) for more details.

Comment: Edited answer to count as a valid one, hope is does now :-)